# EmguCv copy image part to dest with offset

Tags: c#, image, opencv, emgucv

I've got an image and I've got a mask (which isn't a rectangle) and a destination empty image with the size of the mask's bounding box. So the interested image part should fit there. How can I tell emgucv to copy the masked image to the destination without having the same number of dimensions of the destination image?

So something like:
img:
(3*3 image)

```
3,3,3 4,4,4 5,5,5
6,6,6 7,7,7 8,8,8
9,9,9 1,1,1 2,2,2
```

mask:
I'm not interested in the top row and 1 last pixel
(3*3 gray image)

```
0,0,0 0,0,0 0,0,0
1,1,1 1,1,1 1,1,1
1,1,1 1,1,1 0,0,0
```

dest (before copy):
(3*2 empty image)

```
0,0,0 0,0,0 0,0,0
0,0,0 0,0,0 0,0,0
```

dest (after copy):
(3*2 image)

```
6,6,6 7,7,7 8,8,8
9,9,9 1,1,1 0,0,0
```